# ItemsControl item selection binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, selection, itemscontrol

I have a view defined as below,

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding C1.Coll1}>
    ....
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:C2}">
        <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
            <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Coll2}/>
        </Expander>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The associated view model is something like this,

```
Class C1
{
    public Coll1<C2>;
}

Class C2
{
    Public Name,
    Public Coll2
}
```

I can bind a selection event of listbox into C2. When this event fires I want to fire it up to C1. What are my alternatives? I tried binding the selection event into C1 but it did not work. Is there a way to bind it or are there any alternatives to do that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: Please ignore the syntax here, I am only trying to demonstrate my view point with minimum code. If anyone is interested in full code let me know I can share it.

Comment: `ItemSorce` won't compile and that's where I stop reading your code. Always copy/paste the actual stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The ItemsSource of your ItemsControl is *already* in C1.

So you just need to create a two-way binding of the SelectedItem of your ItemsSource to a property in C1.  You need to change from an ItemsControl to a descendant of Selector, e.g. ListView.  You still have control over the ItemsSource and the appearance / templates.

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding CollectionOfC2Items} 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedC2Item, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

By setting the UpdateSourceTrigger to 'PropertyChanged' you will force the property in C1 (the binding source) to update as soon as the selection changes in the ItemsControl.

Comment: Thanks for the response James, can we add a binding for SelectedItem in the ItemsControl?

Comment: You are correct - there is no concept of SelectedItem with an ItemsControl.  Unless you really need the ItemsControl, why not just use a List ... I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I need an itemscontrol as the list content is dynamic. The number of items (Expander + Listbox, that behaves like a grouped listbox) and the items in the Listbox keep changing. If you have a better approach let me know.

Comment: You can dynamically change the content of a ListView or ListBox - and control the appearance of the items within.  I don't really understand the need for an ItemsControl,  ListView/ListBox ultimately inherits from ItemsControl anyway?

Comment: James, In addition to content the number of listboxes that need to generate itself is not constant.

Comment: to be more precise, this is what I am doing visually,        IttemGroup1  -> item1, item2, item3. ItemGroup2 -> Item1, item2, item3. It is a collection of group of items. The expander behaves as a collapsible group. This collection of groups is binded. Based on a criteria there could be only 1 group item or more than 1. Hope I make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79703/discussion-between-bub-and-james-harcourt).